# Default parameter in C++

Tags: c++, documentation

when using default parameter, I set

```
void method1(float v, float w =1.0)
```

Is this a good practice to use the comment in the definition like

```
void class::method1(float v, float w /*=1/0*/)
```

Comment: What is your goal? The first line is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not (documentation relevant) commenting at definitions at all. Only for declarations in header files.

Comment: I frequently do it that way. It is helpful if you arrive at the definition in the debugger from a call that does not specify the optional parameter. However, you need to make sure to update it if the declaration changes.

Comment: @Dithermaster Labels/Symbols, yes! But not relevant for documentation as asked for ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer some doxygen compliant documentation this way:

```
/**
 * Description of the behavior/purpose of your method
 * 
 * @param v The float 'v' (whatever this means)
 * @param w Optional float 'w' (whatever this means), default value is 1.0.
 */
void method1(float v, float w =1.0);
```

Usually I'm not going to put additional comments with implementation specific blocks,

Comment: `default value is 1.0` redocument as function declaration.

Comment: @billz Don't get it, do you mean to provide `void method1(float v, float w);` separately/additionally??

Answer (score 0):

Intellisence in most of the IDE will work, if not you can keep comment as well. I do not think any harm in this.